# Oracle constraint : Records with same values on some column but not all

Tags: sql, oracle

I have

```
table1 | col A | col B | col C | col D
           1       2       2       2
           4       2       2       2
```

Which constraints can I use in order to make 2 entries that can have different values on Col A, but NEVER same values on Col B, C, D at the same time ?

You can think of 2 ill people that can't have same appointement date (assuming date is set by 3 columns and not 1)

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the combination of B+C+D as unique, you can do it by adding a unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE YOURTABLE ADD CONSTRAINT UC_BCD UNIQUE (B,C,D)
```